# IOError while doing virtualenv venv in Python Mac OSX

Tags: python, macos, virtualenv

I am getting the following error, whenever I do `virtualenv venv`. I have installed virtualenv via `sudo pip install --user virtualenv`

```
New python executable in /Users/rajrohit/Desktop/Work/LambdaAnsible/TestLambda/venv/bin/python
Please make sure you remove any previous custom paths from your /Users/rajrohit/.pydistutils.cfg file.
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
  Complete output from command /Users/rajrohit/Desk...mbda/venv/bin/python - setuptools pip wheel:
  Collecting setuptools
  Using cached setuptools-34.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pip
Collecting wheel
Collecting packaging>=16.8 (from setuptools)
  Using cached packaging-16.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting appdirs>=1.4.0 (from setuptools)
  Using cached appdirs-1.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting six>=1.6.0 (from setuptools)
  Using cached six-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyparsing (from packaging>=16.8->setuptools)
  Using cached pyparsing-2.1.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: six, pyparsing, packaging, appdirs, setuptools, pip, wheel
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/wheel.py", line 478, in move_wheel_files
    generated.extend(maker.make(spec))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/distlib/scripts.py", line 372, in make
    self._make_script(entry, filenames, options=options)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/distlib/scripts.py", line 276, in _make_script
    self._write_script(scriptnames, shebang, script, filenames, ext)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/distlib/scripts.py", line 250, in _write_script
    self._fileop.write_binary_file(outname, script_bytes)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/distlib/util.py", line 407, in write_binary_file
    with open(path, 'wb') as f:
IOError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/bin/easy_install'
----------------------------------------
...Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 713, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 945, in create_environment
    download=download,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 901, in install_wheel
    call_subprocess(cmd, show_stdout=False, extra_env=env, stdin=SCRIPT)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 797, in call_subprocess
    % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command /Users/rajrohit/Desk...mbda/venv/bin/python - setuptools pip wheel failed with error code 2
```

**How do I work with this permissions error, and make virtualenv work properly?**

Comment: you can take a reference of this stackoverflow post http://askubuntu.com/questions/675296/changing-ownership-operation-not-permitted-even-as-root

Comment: why do you use sudo ton install a virtualenv ?

Answer (score 0):

I've always had permission issues when running/modifying the default OSX python interpreter. Currently I use PyEnv (https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv) which installs separate user modifiable python interpreters and together with pyenv-virtualenv (https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv-virtualenv) it works like a charm. I've never had issues since the change.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had similar issues setting up a new machine, I found this solution worked best.
https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/209583/226131

A more detailed explanation is contained within the same question. 
https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/223163/226131

TLDR: install a user-modifiable version of python `brew install python` then you can just pip install.